# Javascript Container Scroll Snap Issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a feature where I scroll snap to the closest child div. 
This works partially when i scroll slowly. But when I try to scroll fast (using the mousewheel), the scroll animation behaves incorrectly. I think the childToScrollTop variable is not cleared a set correctly but I cant identify how to update it correctly.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const child = document.createElement("div");
  child.classList.add("child");
  child.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
  container.appendChild(child);
}

let childToScrollTop = 0;
let timeout;
let scrollInterval;
const WAIT_TIME = 200;
const childHeight = 200;

container.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    let scrollTop = container.scrollTop;
    let mod = container.scrollTop % childHeight;
    let q = container.scrollTop / childHeight;
    if (mod !== 0) {
      childToScrollTop = Math.round(q) * childHeight;
      if (scrollInterval) {
       clearInterval(scrollInterval);
      }
      animateContainer();
    }
  }, WAIT_TIME);
});

function animateContainer() {
  var step = 20;
  scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
   const diff = container.scrollTop - childToScrollTop;
    if (diff >= -1 * step && diff <= step) {
      container.scrollTop = childToScrollTop;
      clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    }
    if (container.scrollTop > childToScrollTop) {
     container.scrollTop = container.scrollTop - step;
    } else if (container.scrollTop < childToScrollTop) {
      container.scrollTop = container.scrollTop + step;
    }
  }, 15);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Gif to demo the issue:

[image]

Facing the issue on Chrome

Comment: Seems to be working for me (Chrome 60+).

Comment: You need to scroll really fast using the mousewheel to notice it.

Comment: Can approve what @ScottMarcus said, it works perfectly fine in Chrome 62

Comment: I added a giphy link to demo the issue.

Comment: What browser are you seeing the problem on? Chrome FF and Safari are fine here (flinging as fast as I can.)

Comment: I am facing the issue on Chrome. havent tried on other browsers yet.

Comment: Unable to replicate in Chrome or FF (Linux)

Comment: I did scroll really fast using the mouse wheel. Seems fine.